# Python pptx link to Excel file - how is it saved? Is it possible to update it?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I have created a PowerPoint presentation which has an Excel range pasted as a link in it. This is done through copying a range in Excel, then in PowerPoint paste special and paste link. When the underlying excel range changes, I can update the link in PowerPoint so that it has the latest data.

Can this be done with python-pptx? Where is the link information stored? I can't see anything relevant in `prs.slides[0].shapes[0].element` nor `prs.slides[0].shapes[0].click_action.hyperlink`

Comment: You can read python-pptx docs : http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#api-documentation

Comment: There is no direct API support in `python-pptx` for this, so no need to go searching for it in the docs. It's an interesting question how it's implemented in the .pptx XML. I'd recommend looking at the XML for a slide that contains *only* such a link (makes finding it in the XML a lot easier). I'm sure there's a relationship involved because of the external reference.